# Adding a CSS class to date_select

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following date_select helper. I want to add a class but it's not producing the HTML.

```
<%= date_select :recipient, :birthday, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :start_year => 1920, :end_year => 2013, :class => "input-mini" %>
```

I've also tried it with a hash as some solutions suggest but I get a syntax error:

```
<%= date_select :recipient, :birthday, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :start_year => 1920, :end_year => 2013, {:class => "input-mini"} %>
```

Not sure I really understand when and how to format it with a hash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= date_select :recipient, :birthday, 
:order => [:day, :month, :year], 
:start_year => 1920, 
:end_year => 2013, 
:html=>{:class => "input-mini"} 
%>
```

**Update: For Rails 5**

```
<%= date_select :recipient, :birthday, 
               {
                :order => [:day, :month, :year], 
                :start_year => 1920, 
                :end_year => 2013
               }, 
               {:class => "input-mini"}  %>
```

Answer (score 31):

The validated answer did not work for me, what worked was:

```
<%= date_select
    :recipient,
    :birthday,
    {:order => [:day, :month, :year], :start_year => 1920, :end_year => 2013},
    {:class => "input-mini"}
%>
```

Which makes more sense according to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select):

```
date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Answer (score 0):

try

clas inside html hash like     `:html=>{:class=>'input-mini'}`

```
<%= date_select :recipient, :birthday, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :start_year => 1920, :end_year => 2013, :html=>{:class => "input-mini"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As we can see on the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select), the `date_select` helper want the specific parameters:

```
date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

For me just don´t add the **method** option and leave the options hash `{}` empty worked perfectly:

```
datetime_select(:recipient, {}, {:class => 'custom-select'})
```

Or if you want to use with `:birthday` param you can simply use:

```
datetime_select(:recipient, :birthday, {}, {:class => 'custom-select'})
```